# d3.js: sort nested arrays

Tags: javascript

How can I sort the nested arrays of an array like the one below please? I would like to sort array `prob` and then rearrange `name` accordingly so that relationship is maintained.

```
var records = [
{ num: 1, name: ["Sam", "Amy", "John"], prob: [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]},
{ num: 2, name: ["Nick", "Carol", "Sam"], prob: [0.5, 0.03, 0.47] },
{ num: 3, name: ["Ken", "Eric", "Ely"], prob: [0.1, 0.3, 0.6] },
{ num: 4, name: ["Amy", "Sam", "John"], prob: [0.6, 0.3, 0.1] },
{ num: 5, name: ["Chris", "Donna", "Jeff"], prob: [0.25, 0.55, 0.2] }
]
```

I would like to end-up with:

```
var records = [
{ num: 1, name: ["John", "Sam", "Amy"], prob: [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]},
{ num: 2, name: ["Nick", "Sam", "Carol"], prob: [0.5, 0.47, 0.03] },
{ num: 3, name: ["Ely", "Eric", "Ken"], prob: [0.6, 0.3, 0.1] },
{ num: 4, name: ["Amy", "Sam", "John"], prob: [0.6, 0.3, 0.1] },
{ num: 5, name: ["Donna", "Chris", "Jeff"], prob: [0.55, 0.25, 0.2] }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: combine the elements of `name` and `prop` in an array of objects with `name` and `prop` properties. sort this array by `prop`, create the `name` and `prop` array from this sorted array of objects

Comment: how is this d3.js related?

Comment: Can you clarify "name accordingly so that relationship is maintained.". How are you sorting the names array (in what order).

Comment: **array of objects**, zip the arrays `name` and `prob`

Comment: What have you found in your research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution: we could store `names` and `prob` in `pairs` and sorting both values at the same time, then we assign that names and probs sorted to the main object:

```js
var records = [
{ num: 1, name: ["Sam", "Amy", "John"], prob: [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]},
{ num: 2, name: ["Nick", "Carol", "Sam"], prob: [0.5, 0.03, 0.47] },
{ num: 3, name: ["Ken", "Eric", "Ely"], prob: [0.1, 0.3, 0.6] },
{ num: 4, name: ["Amy", "Sam", "John"], prob: [0.6, 0.3, 0.1] },
{ num: 5, name: ["Chris", "Donna", "Jeff"], prob: [0.25, 0.55, 0.2] }
];

var pairs = records.map((e,i)=>
e.name.map((e2,i2)=>[e2,records[i].prob[i2]]).sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1])
);

records.map((e, i) => {
  e.name = pairs[i].map(o => o[0])
  e.prob = pairs[i].map(o => o[1])      
})

console.log(records)
```

Comment: what is the need to keep the intermediate results of `pairs`?

Comment: @rioV8 to sort both values at the same time

Comment: No. Just sort `el`. indentation helps readability. and `;` are also helpful, construct `el` with `.map()`

Comment: `el` is an array you can sort, === `e` you use in `pairs.forEach`

Comment: another good point @rioV8, thanks. I was too focused on the main logic

Comment: have a look at my refactored answer

Comment: @rioV8 smart refactoring

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest if you turn your arrays of `name`s and `prob`s into objects to preserve the links between each name and the probability. The object's properties can then be sorted as if they were an array using a custom sort function.

```
records.forEach( function (d) {
  var temp = {};

  // create objects with key <name> and value <prob>
  // (this makes the assumption that prob values may not be unique, but names are)
  d.name.forEach( function(e,i) {
    temp[e] = d.prob[i];
  })

  // get an array of the object keys (the name), and sort them by the object values
  // (the corresponding prob), descending. Replace the existing `name` array with this.
  d.name = Object.keys(temp).sort(function(a, b){ 
    return temp[b] - temp[a];
  });

  // sort the prob values in descending order (with d3.descending, since you mentioned d3)
  d.prob = d.prob.sort(function(a,b){ return b - a; });
});
```

If you aren't using d3, replace `d3.descending` with the standard descending sort function.

Comment: using 2 different sorting methods and both hard coded is waiting for a very hard to track bug if the code is modified. Use the same sorting function.

Comment: d3.descending performs the same sorting function as a standard numeric sort.

Comment: thanks a lot everyone, this is what i ended up with, pretty much what rioV8 and Emmeus proposed: var out = [];
     for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++)
     { t = d3.zip(records[i].name, records[i].prob);
         t.sort(function (a, b) {
                 return b[1] - a[1]; });
         var name = t.map(function (d, i) {
             return d[0]
         });
         var prob = t.map(function (d, i) {
             return d[1]
         });
         out.push({
             num: records[i].num,
             name: name,
             prob: prob,
         }); }

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring Emeeus answer

```js
var records = [
{ num: 1, name: ["Sam", "Amy", "John"], prob: [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]},
{ num: 2, name: ["Nick", "Carol", "Sam"], prob: [0.5, 0.03, 0.47] },
{ num: 3, name: ["Ken", "Eric", "Ely"], prob: [0.1, 0.3, 0.6] },
{ num: 4, name: ["Amy", "Sam", "John"], prob: [0.6, 0.3, 0.1] },
{ num: 5, name: ["Chris", "Donna", "Jeff"], prob: [0.25, 0.55, 0.2] }
];

records.forEach((e, i) => {
  var el = e.name.map((e2,i2)=>[e2,e.prob[i2]]);
  el.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  e.name = el.map(o => o[0]);
  e.prob = el.map(o => o[1]);
});

console.log(records);
```